# Defining parameter as function without losing properties of the derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, parameters

I have built a code that is later on solved dynamically depending on values I set using Manipulate while plotting. However, I came across a problem I cannot resolve. So, I defined `cds[k_,eos_,cs_]` as a function. Normally, it is a parameter. But I want the parameter to be a function, which dynamically adapts when `k,eos` or `cs` is changed. The problem is, that the parameter (which now is defined by `cds[.]`) is part o the function `F[k_,eos_,cs_]`, which loses its propertie of the second derivative to be negative at all times. So, when `cds[.]` is not a function, but a parameter within space of zero and one, the second derivative of `F[.]` is always negative. The question arising now is, how I can achieve `cds[.]` to adapt to the given variables while it doesn´t alter the properties of `F[.]`, as in the case, when `cds[.]` would normally be a parameter.

```
param[eos_] = 1/eos-1
l = 1
cds[k_,eos_,cs_] = ((cs*k^(1/eos))/(k - cs*k + cs*k^(1/eos)))
F[k_,eos_,cs_] = (((1 - cds[k, eos, cs])*l^(-param[eos]) + cds[k,eos,cs]*k^(-param[eos]))^(-1/param[eos]))/l
FK[k_,eos_,cs_] = Evaluate[D[F[k,eos,cs],k]]
FKK[k_,eos_,cs_] = Evaluate[D[F[k,eos,cs],k,k]]
```

Comment: Why are you using `=` instead of `:=` for all these function definitions? And better not to use `l=1` as `l` looks like `1` on many monitors which makes hard to read. any other letter is better.

Comment: I used `=` because it didn´t make any difference for my calculations. Regarding the `l` variable I agree, but since it´s value doesn´t change from one, its redundant anyway.

Comment: Since you are using `Set` (i.e., `=` ), the RHS of your expressions are evaluated immediately, making the use of `Evaluate` unnecessary. `Evaluate` would be needed if you used `SetDelayed` since the derivatives must be taken before a value is assigned to `k`. If you include `Simplify` in the definitions for `F`, `FK`, and `FKK`; their expressions will be cleaner.